# UINavigationController subclass Acts differently on iOS7 and dropping ViewControllers from self.viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

In one of my apps I'm using a subclassed `UINavigationController` in order to push `ViewControllers` from Right to left instead the usual left to right. I'm using the next code to replace the pop and push animation to achieve this. it has been working great on all iOS lower than iOS 7.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

**UINavigationController subclass:**

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Add the viewController and a fake controller without animation. Then pop the fake controller with animation.
    UIViewController *fakeController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [super setViewControllers:[[self viewControllers] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController, fakeController, nil]] animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"Log1: %d",[self.viewControllers count]);
    [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    NSLog(@"Log2: %d",[self.viewControllers count]);
    [self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:Nil afterDelay:5];
}

-(void)test
{
      NSLog(@"Log3: %d",[self.viewControllers count]);
}
```

**On iOS 6 and down the log will show:**

```
Log1:3
Log2:2
Log3:2
```

**On iOS 7 the log will show:**

```
Log1:3
Log2:2
Log3:1 //<---This is my problem
```

In order to be extra sure this is happening because of iOS 7 I've created a new project with 3 empty Viewcontrollers and a subclassed `UINavigationController` and the above method. I'm still getting different results on iOS 7 and on iOS 6.

Why the first `ViewController` in the array is also removed? How can I fix it?

Comment: How about push the `viewController` and the `fakeViewController` instead of setting it directly.

Comment: Pushing the viewcontrollers will give me the same results on iOS 7: Log1:3 Log2:2 Log3:1